# How to apply API query through a list of dates in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run this piece of code to retrieve weather data while dynamically changing the start and end date from the two lists created below:

```
    London<-weather_api("premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=8085db2e3cc041239be151146200304&q=London&format=json&date=2018-01-01&enddate=2018-02-01&tp=24")

    start_dates_list <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), by="months")
    end_dates_list <- seq(as.Date("2018-02-01"), as.Date("2020-04-01"), by="months")
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `weather_api` comes from what package? Please start your scripts with `library(pkgname)` to load necessary packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```r
start_dates_list <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), by="months")
end_dates_list <- seq(as.Date("2018-02-01"), as.Date("2020-04-01"), by="months")
allURLs <- sprintf("premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=8085db2e3cc041239be151146200304&q=London&format=json&date=%s&enddate=%s&tp=24",
                   start_dates_list, end_dates_list)
alldata <- lapply(allURLs, weather_api)
```

And depending on how the output is formatting, you can combine the data with one of:

```r
dat <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, alldata)
dat <- data.table::rbindlist(alldata)
dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(alldata)
```

You might also want to go to your account page (for where-ever `weather_api` reaches out to) and change your api key, since you've now broadcast it to the world ... and there are no take-backs/undos.